# Oracle database in data source as {e5e86-......}

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, odp.net-managed

[Data Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0O0SL.png) Check this image. Instead of oracle database i am getting {......} this variables. why so ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: No idea; looks like something contained in Windows Registry. If you search through it, can you find such a string?

Comment: yes. it is in Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\DataProviders\{068377A0-9A77-45eb-9C83-D6DE15067E0E} .

Name : AssociatedSource  Data : {E5E86CD6-6454-4fdd-910F-DC5DFC73EB45}

Comment: Backup registry. Change that meaningless string to something *smarter*. See how it behaves. Leave it if it works, restore previous state if it doesn't. Note that messing up with registry might harm your computer.